Receiving A "java.lang.NullPointerException" When Trying To Perform A Post API Call Using Retrofit
Using Retrofit and Jetpack Compose, I'm trying to perform a @POST API call but whenever I do so the complier throws an exception that states "java.lang.NullPointerException". It paticular I'm trying to create a session using the The Movie Database API.
There are three steps involved in the process of creating a session.

First Step - generating a request token using a @GET API call. This worked successfully.
Second Step - after generating a request token you will be redirected to a webpage where you will be prompted to allow permission for your application to access information related to your TMDB account. This also works successfully.
Third Step - this is the part where you actually have to create the session using a @POST API call. It doesn't work. It throws a "java.lang.NullPointerException".

Here is where the code begins
This is the data class the holds the values of the RequestToken
data class RequestToken(
    val expires_at: String = "",
    val request_token: String = "",
    val success: Boolean = false
)

This is the data class the holds the values of the SessionId 
data class SessionId(
    val session_id: String = "",
    val success: Boolean = false
)

Here is the API interface. It hold the API calls
interface ApiInterface {

    @GET("authentication/token/new?api_key=$apiKey")
    suspend fun getRequestToken(): Response<RequestToken>

    @POST("authentication/session/new?api_key=$apiKey")
    suspend fun createSession(@Body requestToken: String): Response<SessionId>
}

This is the Retrofit instance. It contains the base URL.
object RetrofitInstance {
    val api: ApiOperations by lazy {
        Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("https://api.themoviedb.org/3/")
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build()
            .create(ApiOperations::class.java)
    }
}

This is the ViewModel that holds the RequestToken, the SessionId, and the URL for the TMDB login and access request page
// Global Instance Of ApiViewModel
val apiViewModel = ApiViewModel()

class ApiViewModel: ViewModel() {

    var requestToken by mutableStateOf(RequestToken())

    var sessionId by mutableStateOf(SessionId())

    fun accessRequestPageUrl(requestToken: String): String {
    return "https://www.themoviedb.org/authenticate/${requestToken}"}

}

Here are the functions that initiate the API calls and handle exceptions. They are also located in the ViewModel
fun getRequestToken(context: Context) {
    viewModelScope.launch {
        try {
          apiViewModel.requestToken = RetrofitInstance.api.getRequestToken().body()!!
            }catch (e: Exception){
                Toast.makeText(context, e.toString, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                return@launch
      }
   }
}

    fun createSession(context: Context, requestToken: String) {
    viewModelScope.launch {
        try {
          apiViewModel.sessionId = RetrofitInstance.api.createSession(
              context = context, requestToken = requestToken).body()!!
            }catch (e: Exception){
                Toast.makeText(context, e.toString, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                return@launch
      }
   }
}

Here is the UI
val context = LocalContext.current

// Conditional That Redirects User To Login Page If Request Token Is Not Empty
if (apiViewModel.requestToken.request_token.isNotEmpty()) {
        context.startActivity(
            Intent(
                Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                Uri.parse(apiViewModel.accessRequestPageUrl(apiViewModel.requestToken.request_token)))
        )
    }

Column(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()
    ) {

    // Button That Creates The Request Token
    Button(onClick = {apiViewModel.getRequestToken(context = context)}){
       Text(text = "Login")
   }

    // Button That Creates The Session
    Button(onClick = {
            apiViewModel.createSession(
            context = context, requestToken = apiViewModel.requestToken)}) {

    }
}

Well that's all for the code. Whenever I click on the create request token button, it works as intended. After a few seconds I am redirected to a webpage that either asks me to login if I'm not or allow access to profile information if I am logged in. It's when I click on the create session button that things don't work. An exception is handled and a toast is displayed stating "java.lang.NullPointerException". I tried adding an @Headers annotation above the createSession API call containing headers from the documentation but that didn't help.
If anyone can fix this or at least lead me in the right direction, that would be greatly appreciated.

"An exception is handled and a toast is displayed stating "java.lang.NullPointerException"" -- get rid of the Toast calls. Log the exceptions to Logcat, so you get the full stack trace and can see exactly where in your code the exception is coming from. If you cannot interpret the stack trace, edit your question, add the stack trace to the question, and add in any code needed to interpret the stack trace that is not already in the question.

Okay after removing the try and catch block and letting the app crash, the log cat tells me the error comes from the .body()!! part of the createSession function. I can successfully make the API call on Postman but not my app. Postman requires that I set the body to raw and JSON. I'm not sure how to do that in Retrofit.
